# Big-Oh Notation

Tags: asymptotics

I'm given to the following relationship:

$$C(x) = C(\lfloor(\frac x2)\rfloor) + x, C(1)=2$$

I do not understand how my teacher says to calculate big O. Any help to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Put $x=2^n$ and solve to find the series.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but that has made me even more lost.

Comment: @user80490 Another hint: it will result in a geometric series.

Comment: @user80490 Once you get the geometric series you are done. On applying the substitution, the expression becomes $C(2^n) = C(2^{n-1}) + 2^n$. Now continue expanding $C(2^{n-1})$ and so on to get the GP. Find the sum and now replace $2^n $ by $x$. You should get a linear expression.